# Calculate the derivative of sin5x using limits

Tags: limits, trigonometry, derivatives

Well, that's it. How do you calculate $\frac{d}{dx} {\sin5x}$ using the limit formula for derivatives?

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$

I managed to get a lot of sines and cosines using trigonometric identities, but got stuck halfway. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(5x+5h)-\sin 5x}{h}
      &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin 5x\cos 5h + \cos 5x\sin 5h-\sin 5x}{h} \\
      &= \lim_{h\to 0} \left(\sin 5x\frac{\cos 5h-1}{h} + \cos 5x\frac{\sin 5h}{h}\right) \\
      &= 5\lim_{h\to 0} \left(\sin 5x\frac{\cos 5h-1}{5h} + \cos 5x\frac{\sin 5h}{5h}\right) \\
      &= 5\lim_{k\to 0} \left(\sin 5x\frac{\cos k-1}{k} + \cos 5x\frac{\sin k}{k}\right) \\
      &= 5\cos 5x
\end{align*}
assuming you already know the limits $\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{\cos k-1}{k} = 0$ and $\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{\sin k}{k} =1$.

Comment: There is a suspicious missing $5$ in here that I think would come from $5(x+h)$ instead of $5x + h$ initially.

Comment: It's supposed to be $\sin(5x+5h)-\sin(5x)$ in the numerator of the first fraction. The answer is supposed to be $5\cos(5x)$.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\cos5h-1}{5h}=1$, which can be seen by substituting $u=5h$.

Comment: Yes it must be 5cos5x but for your second comment it is zero only @columbus8myhw

Comment: Derp. I meant to say that it equalled zero. Sorry!

Comment: Ack. Thanks, all.